# MERN - Heroku and Netlify deploy. -Authentication part isnt working

Tags: authentication, heroku, mern, netlify

I deployed my MERN projects backend in heroku and frontend in netlify.
The netlify part displays data from heroku.
But authentication like login/signup is not working.
Error in console is
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
and

xhr.js:220          POST https://mern-corner-blog.herokuapp.com/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your path to that registered api.
It might be the case that the spelling is wrong or the path.

Check and revert back.